# passing function as constructor parameter to base class constructor while initializing

Tags: c++, class, constructor, callback, function-pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<typeinfo>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class foo;
class bar
{
    public:
        bar()
        {
        }
        bar(void (*getNextValue)(void)):memberFunctionPointer(getNextValue)
        {
        }
        void calltoderivedslass()
        {
            //  *memberFunctionPointer();
            ((bar*)this)->bar::memberFunctionPointer;
        }
        void (foo::*memberFunctionPointer)();
};

class foo : public bar
{
    public:
        foo( ):bar(static_cast<foo::*memberFunctionPointer>(&foo::hello))
        {
        }
        void hello()
        {
            printf("Hello \n\n");
        }
};
void byebye()
{
    cout << "bye" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    foo testfoo;
    //((testfoo).*(testfoo.memberFunctionPointer))();
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
classname.cpp: In constructor "bar::bar(void (*)())":
classname.cpp:15:68: error: cannot convert "void (*)()" to "void (foo::*)()" in initialization
classname.cpp: In constructor "foo::foo()":
classname.cpp:29:25: error: expected type-specifier
classname.cpp:29:25: error: expected ">"
classname.cpp:29:25: error: expected "("
classname.cpp:29:30: error: expected unqualified-id before "*" token
classname.cpp:31:2: error: expected "{" at end of input
```

**Expectations:**

I want to initialize the base class  function pointer to initialize it points to derived class member function. I want to initialize that while creating object of derived class. From base class i want to call derived class function using the acquired function pointer.

Thanks in advance for all.

Comment: If you use OOP correctly there is no need to use function pointers... Consider the programmers who will have to maintain you code..

Comment: yeah,there is a requirement to use function pointer.
A callback has to be called when some error occurs in a DB reading, So i am in need of function pointer, Not to make difficulty in maintaining the code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor for `bar` is wrong.

The constructor `bar(void (*getNextValue)(void))` does not expect a member function pointer of a function of `foo` and therefore initializing `bar::memberFunctionPointer` is not possible with the type of `getNextValue`.

You need to change the parameter in the constructor to `void (foo::*getNextValue)(void)` for this to compile.

Yet the overall design does not really seem right to me... So I think the answer of @wasthishelpful is more helpful ;-)

Comment: That error was fixed:) but still this error

classname.cpp: In constructor âfoo::foo()â:
classname.cpp:29:25: error: expected type-specifier
classname.cpp:29:25: error: expected â>â
classname.cpp:29:25: error: expected â(â
classname.cpp:29:30: error: expected unqualified-id before â*â token
classname.cpp:31:2: error: expected â{â at end of input

Comment: Simon-kraemer

This is my derived class constructor i am trying to pass function pointer to base class constructor

foo( ):bar(static_cast<foo::*memberFunctionPointer>(&foo::hello))

please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes you do, but the receiving side implicitly converts the member function back.
BTW: You don't need to cast in foo. `&foo::hello` is already the correct type. Have a look at this: https://godbolt.org/g/Bw72R1

And please check the other answer as it is definitely the better solution!

Comment: Thanks -Simon Kraemer once again.

Compilation error is fixed. But i am not getting my desired output.
 testfoo.calltoderivedslass(); i want my derived class function hello() to be called, but that is not happening.

Is any thing wrong with this syntax,
((bar*)this)->bar::memberFunctionPointer;

Answer (score 2):

Looks like virtual methods to me:

```
class bar
{
    public:
        bar()
        {
        }
        void calltoderivedslass()
        {
            this->hello();
        }
        virtual void hello() = 0;
};

class foo : public bar
{
    public:
        foo( )
        {
        }
        void hello() override
        {
            printf("Hello \n\n");
        }
};
```

---

An other way may be to use the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern ([CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp)) to achieve static polymorphism:

```
template<typename T>
class bar
{
    public:
        bar()
        {
        }
        void calltoderivedslass()
        {
            static_cast<T*>(this)->hello();
        }
};

class foo : public bar<foo>
{
    public:
        foo( )
        {
        }
        void hello()
        {
            printf("Hello \n\n");
        }
};
```

---

If you really want to keep pointers to member functions, you may consider [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) bound to `this`:

```
class bar
{
    public:
        bar()
        {
        }
        template<typename F>
        bar(F&& getNextValue):memberFunctionPointer(std::forward<F>(getNextValue))
        {
        }
        void calltoderivedslass()
        {
            this->memberFunctionPointer();
        }
        std::function<void()> memberFunctionPointer;
};

class foo : public bar
{
    public:
        foo( ):bar(std::bind(&foo::hello, this))
        {
        }
        void hello()
        {
            printf("Hello \n\n");
        }
};
```

With an extended usage I'm guessing:

```
void byebye()
{
    cout << "bye" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    bar testbar(byebye);
    testbar.calltoderivedslass(); // not a derived class, but it works
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, When i have use your code, i am getting errors as below,

Comment: @KiruthikaPalanivelu There is no "errors as below" ^^ Anyway, did you add `#include <functional>` to use `std::function`?

Comment: thank you for your answer, When i have use your code, i am getting errors as below,

error: expected â,â or â...â before â&&â token
error: âfunctionâ in namespace âstdâ does not name a type
In constructor âbar::bar(F)â:
error: class âbarâ does not have any field named âmemberFunctionPointerâ
error: âforwardâ is not a member of âstdâ
error: expected primary-expression before â>â token
error: âgetNextValueâ was not declared in this scope
In member function âvoid bar::calltoderivedslass()â:
error: âclass barâ has no member named âmemberFunctionPointerâ

Comment: @KiruthikaPalanivelu did you include `functional`? What compiler are you using? My code needs C++11 support

Comment: Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Yes!! I got compilation terminated when i uses that.

kiru4.cpp: In constructor âfoo::foo()â:
kiru4.cpp:29:20: error: âbindâ is not a member of âstdâ

Comment: @KiruthikaPalanivelu I don't think gcc 4.6.3 has enough C++11 support. But you can try virtual methods or CRTP ;)

Comment: 16:14: error: expected â,â or â...â before â&&â token
23:9: error: âfunctionâ in namespace âstdâ does not name a type
 In constructor âbar::bar(F)â:
16:31: error: class âbarâ does not have any field named âmemberFunctionPointerâ
16:53: error: âforwardâ is not a member of âstdâ
16:67: error: expected primary-expression before â>â token
16:69: error: âgetNextValueâ was not declared in this scope
 In member function âvoid bar::calltoderivedslass()â:
21:19: error: âclass barâ has no member named âmemberFunctionPointerâ
 In constructor âfoo::foo()â:
29:20: error: âbindâ is not a member